# function empty() doesn't work on checkboxes

Tags: php, html

I have this input in html

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkbox-ambulance" name="checkbox-ambulance">
```

Now I want to see if the checkbox is checked in php with this

```
if (empty($_POST['checkbox-ambulance'])) {
   $x = "unchecked";
} else {
   $x = "checked";
}
```

However, it doesn't matter if the checkbox is checked or not, the variable x is always gonna be "unchecked". Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I also tried to use isset(), still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a value for the checkbox (e.g. value='ON')

Because empty string is also regarded as "empty" (see the documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.empty.php) )

Change

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" 
id="checkbox-ambulance" name="checkbox-ambulance">
```

to

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="ON" 
id="checkbox-ambulance" name="checkbox-ambulance">
```

So a sample will be like:

```
<?php

if ($_POST["submit"]) {

if (empty($_POST['checkbox-ambulance'])) {
   $x = "unchecked";
} else {
   $x = "checked";
}

echo $x; 
echo "<br>";
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

}
?>

<form action=# method=POST>
Tick this box (or not):
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="ON" 
id="checkbox-ambulance" name="checkbox-ambulance">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

See this **sample link**:

http://www.createchhk.com/SO/testSO22Jan2022.php#

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: Please use the sample link I posted and try it . Thanks

Comment: @Cristian25 Why does the accepted answer have a follow-up comment stating that it doesn't work? Assigning a value that doesn't cast as `false` in PHP is definitively one of the two possible fixes.

Comment: I forgot to add the update: it was typo in my code actually

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
value=""
```

That means that you cannot use [empty()](https://php.net/empty) to distinguish between checked and unchecked checkboxes because both empty strings (checked) and undefined variables (unchecked) return `false`:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="checkbox-ambulance-checked" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="checkbox-ambulance-unchecked">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

```
array(1) {
  ["checkbox-ambulance-checked"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

```
var_dump(empty(''), empty($variable_that_does_not_exist));
```

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

With your current payload, you need to check for [variable existence](https://php.net/isset):

```
$isChecked = isset($_POST['checkbox-ambulance-checked');
```